# Create a dictionary by appending pandas dataframes in a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary of pandas DataFrames. I want to combine the dataframes in this dictionary to create a dictionary of fewer keys but with larger dataframes as values.

For example, in the example below, I want create `d_new` from `d`.

```
d = {1: pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2],'b':[3,4]}), 
     2: pd.DataFrame({'a':[3,4],'b':[5,6]}),
     3: pd.DataFrame({'a':[10,11],'b':[12,13]}), 
     4: pd.DataFrame({'a':[12,13],'b':[14,15]})}

d_new = {1:pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4],'b':[3,4,5,6]}), 
         3:pd.DataFrame({'a':[10,11,12,13],'b':[12,13,14,15]})}
```

I tried:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict
d_new = defaultdict(pd.DataFrame)
for k_n in [1,3]:
    r = 1 if k_n == 1 else 3
    for k in range(r,r+2):
        d_new[k_n].append(d[k])
```

But this just throws up a dictionary of empty dataframes. We can convert the dataframes into lists and append them and create a dataframe from them later but I want to see if I can save that unnecessary step.

Comment: How is this data being generated/obtained? Are you getting it from an outside source? Or is this sample data thet your are trying to wrangle?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.groupby` to group the keys (here I did it 2 by 2 from the key linear range) and `pandas.concat` to concatenate the dataframes:

```
from itertools import groupby
d_new = {2*k+1: pd.concat([d[e] for e in g])
         for k,g in groupby(d, lambda k: (k-1)//2)}
```

Output:

```
{1:    a  b
 0  1  3
 1  2  4
 0  3  5
 1  4  6,
 3:     a   b
 0  10  12
 1  11  13
 0  12  14
 1  13  15}
```

*NB. I showed you the minimal main concept, but of course you can tweak it to your exact needs (e.g., resetting the index, different condition for grouping)*

If you have non linear range keys (i.e. not 1/2/3...), you'll need to wrap the dictionary in `enumerate`:

```
{2*k+1: pd.concat([x[1] for x in g])
 for k,g in groupby(enumerate(d.values()), lambda k: k[0]//2)}
```

Comment: The ranges are indeed nonlinear. Could you show me how to do it as well?

Comment: @NewbieAF check the update at the bottom of the answer. If you have issues, please provide an example

Comment: By nonlinear, I meant the ranges I need to select are not the same (not divisible by 2 like in the above example). Ideally, I want to select that a range for a particular key from another list. With `lambda x:x[0]//2`, I don't get the ranges I want.

Comment: @NewbieAF this is still not a problem, you can virtually group in any way you want, but I cannot guess what you want to do. Please provide an example.